# image File permission is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

The file is created when the user registers successfully , each user folder thats created is only read/writable by daemon not by admin or anyone else, 
the main users folder is created by me and has all permissions set that needs be and it doesnt even feature the name daemon

The problem I have is that, when I upload an image, it uploads to the directory of that user(the right directory of the users name) and I see it there but the problem is when I want to echo the image onto the page it does not work. 
I use the `moveupload()` function and it moves but it is not able to show the image on the page, all other information is shown on the users page like name ect , but just not the image .What can I do?

This is the code snippet to create the file when user registers . I'm using a mac

```
if(!file_exists("user/$u")) {
mkdir("user/$u",0755);
}
```

Comment: What effective user and group does the file have after created? Can you post the output of `stat (filename)`?

Comment: it has the name of the user the file name. How do i get the stat?

Comment: this is my move result {$moveResult=move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,"user/$log_username/".$main_image); and this is how i echo image on page . i echo it like this <img src="users/$log_username/<?php echo $main_image;?>"width="220" height="200"/>

Comment: @MarcellFülöp i think it could be the file path , how would i refrence this in php  <img src="users/$log_username/<?php echo $main_image;?>"width="220" height="200"/>
 the $log_username refers to the specific users folder which bears their name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using proper HTML syntax for echo-ing your image? You can't simply do an `echo $imagePath;` in PHP, you must user proper HTML syntax for the output.

```
echo "<img src='".$imagePath."' />";
```

**Edit:**

If you're using HTML mixed with php, the HTML output would be as follows:

HTML

```
<img src="<?php echo $log_userpath . "/" . $main_userimage;?>" width="220px" height="300px" />
```

Comment: i echo it like this <img src="users/$log_username/<?php echo $main_image;?>"width="220" height="200"/>

Comment: this is my move result . {$moveResult=move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,"user/$log_username/".$main_image);

Comment: i think you are right. how would i output this properly within php .<img src="users/<?php echo $log_username.'/'.$main_image;?>"width="220" height="200"/>